# Print Xcode build phase output when run via fastlane

Tags: xcode, fastlane, xcode-build-phase

I have a custom Run Script phase in my Xcode project that outputs some information:
[image]

When I build the app via Xcode, I see the output of the script (`Planning build`, `Building for debugging` etc.):

[image]

However, when I build the project via `fastlane gym`, this output is not shown:

[image]

Is there any way I can make that output appear when run through fastlane as well?

Thanks

P.S. This post has gone through a couple of major edits while I realized the root cause better. Apologies for that.

Comment: How is SwiftLint involved? Your screen shots don't show it. Your words don't match your pictures.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. At first I wrote the post using Swiftlint, but then realized that the underlying issue is more generic. After that I edited the post. But forgot to remove all traces of swiftlint. Will remove now. Basically it's a problem with standard output from build script phases when xcodebuild is run from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help, but have you tried adding `-verbose` to the xcodebuild command? You can see the explanation in `man xcodebuild`.

Comment: It's not working unfortunately. But I found out that the problem is actually related to fastlane. The output in the screenshot is from it.

Answer (score 0):

although not perfect,
if you type "warning: Hello" you will see it in the log as a warning

```
echo "warning: Hello"
```